# How to use gTTS in python3 on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, raspbian

I installed gTTS (1.2.0) using pip:

```
$ sudo pip3 install gTTS
```

After starting `python3` I tried to use gTTS as described on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS):

```
>>> from gtts import gTTS
```

The output is the following:

```
Traceback (most resent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .tts import gTTS
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 4, in <module> from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'
```

What can I do to make `from gtts import gTTS` work?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install requests --upgrade` worked for me